# glClearColor is ignored

Tags: c++, glfw

I am trying to set the background color to blue, but glClearColor is completely ignored.
Code:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "3D Shooter", NULL, NULL);
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: Is the window color is black?

Comment: The window is white

Comment: Probably it will be the GLFW initialization issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html